# Dockerize flask application is not storing celery task's logging data in files

Tags: docker, flask, logging, redis, celery-task

## Celery configuration

```
app.config.update(
    broker_url='redis://{}:{}/0'.format(redis_host,redis_port),
    result_backend='redis://{}:{}/0'.format(redis_host,redis_port)
)

stol_distance = 1  # STOL distance 1 km
stol_speed = 50  # STOL speed 50 nautical miles

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['broker_url'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery_app = make_celery(app)
```

## Configure logging

```
log_folder = 'logs'
log_file = os.path.join(log_folder, f'pod_task_{datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}.log')
log_level = logging.DEBUG
```

## Create the log folder if it doesn't exist

```
if not os.path.exists(log_folder):
    os.makedirs(log_folder)
```

## Use RotatingFileHandler for log rotation with negative backupCount

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=10 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=-1)
handler.setLevel(log_level)
```

## Create a log format with a timestamp

```
log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

app.logger.addHandler(handler)


@celery_app.task
def pod_task():
    today = datetime.today()
    previous_date = (today - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    app.logger.info(f"Task Started For {previous_date}")
    app.logger.error(f"Exception in task")
    app.logger.info(f"Task Ended")
    .....
    .....
```

## Schedule the task to run every day at 12:05 AM using Celery Beat

```
celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'daily-task-scheduler': {
        'task': 'celery_config.pod_task',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=0, minute=5),  # Schedule the task to run every day at 12:05 AM
    },
}
```

## Here is my docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app-network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - ${PGADMIN_PORT}:80
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin_data:/var/lib/
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'celery -A celery_config.celery_app worker --loglevel=info -c 8'
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - web
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network


  celery_beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'celery -A celery_config.celery_app beat --loglevel=info'
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - web
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  redis:
    image: redis
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

volumes:
  pgdata:
  pgadmin_data:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Everything is working fine when I run the application without docker. But when I try to run the same thing with docker, folder and file create as expected, but the file is not modifying which supposed to get modified with some data.